# Как убрать название приложения сверху экрана в android?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как поменять текст в этой панели или убрать её совсем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вставь в теге `<activity>`, в которой хочешь убрать title код:
**android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"**

Добавить в файл манифеста.
Должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
```

Comment: Вставил в главный constraintlayout, не получилось(

Comment: @НикитаПопов это в манифесте надо писать

Answer (score 0):

В манифесте измените строку на

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

потом в `string.xml` в строке измените

```
string name="app_name">Ваше название</string>
```

или уберите, и будет счастье.

Answer (score 0):

Просто напишите в методе onCreate в MainActivity:

```
 supportActionBar?.hide()
```